# Adding onclick event to view without delta function on Monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android

I know I can add an onclick handler to a button with:

```
button.Click += (sender, e) => 
{
};
```

But is it possible to do something like?:

```
EventHandler eh=new EventHandler(OnSaveButtonClick);
v.Click += OnSaveButtonClick;
```

For me second option allways throws a SystemNullException at the v.Click asignation.

Is there anyway to accomplish this? I woudl like to do it just to have a cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Sorry for that, but it works now. I think something got wrong with the device, after rebooting it both options worked.